# Writing nested queries in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to write a nested query in Django. It is very simple to do in SQL, but with Django I am having some trouble deciding if I am doing it right or not. I have three models. `Area`, `Location`, and `Measurement`.

**Area**

```
class Area(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    longitude = models.FloatField()
    latitude = models.FloatField()
```

**Location**

```
class Location(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    altitude = models.IntegerField()
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**Measurement**

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
    value = models.FloatField()
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Inside `Area`, I need a function that will return the average of the measurements for this area. So basically, I need the average measurements of all locations for this area. `Area` can have many locations, but locations can have one area. In the `Area` Model, I made this function:

```
def average_measurement(self):
    all_locations = self.location_set.all()
    return all_locations.measurement_set.all().aggregate(Avg('value'))
```

This is my equivalent to writing a nested query in Django. I get all locations first and then find the average of all their measurements. Am I doing this correctly?

On a side question, would this query be equivalent to doing something like this:

```
avg = 0
locations = self.location_set.all()
sum = 0
counter = 0
for l in locations: measurement = l.measurement_set.all()
    if measurement:
        for m in measurement:
           sum += m.value
           counter += 1
if counter != 0:
    avg = sum / counter
return avg
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with a list of objects, it is generally seen as more readable to query the given model directly. So you could instead use:

```
def average_measurement(self):
    return Measurement.objects.filter(location__area = self).aggregate(Avg('value'))['value__avg']
```

You could also adopt this approach in your second example:

```
avg = 0
sum = 0
counter = 0
for m in Measurement.objects.filter(location__area = self):
    sum += m.value
    counter += 1
if counter != 0:
    avg = sum / counter
return avg
```

Comment: I just have a couple questions. Your approach is more readable, but is my approach correct? And why do you add ['value__avg'] at the end?

Comment: Your approach would work because it would be generating the same list of `Measurement` objects. I added the `['value__avg']` at the end in order to return the value directly, as the `aggregate()` function returns a dictionary. If you want the dictionary though (i.e if you were generating multiple aggregates and wanted to return them all), you could remove that part.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity which do you think has the best performance, my approach, your approach, or the for loop approach?

Comment: I think our two approaches would be the same, as I think Django would be executing the same number of queries (maybe even the same query?). However I think the loop approach would be slower as my understanding is that `aggregate()` uses database level APIs to do the calculation, which would be faster than Python code.

Comment: @user2896120 your approach is lengthy and  hence it will decrease performance,  firstly you are fecthing all location after that all mesurment using reverse relation `all_locations.measurement_set.all()`. your code making multiple database query.